# Lync CWE Automation server can't create object

Tags: javascript, activex, lync, activexobject, lync-2013

I developed a CWE extension for Lync 2013. It needs to load an ActiveX control.

I'm testing this on a Windows 7 with IE 8 and a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IE 8.

On Windows Server I added the url as a "Trusted Site" and the ActiveX control is loaded fine. But on Windows 7 I tried to do the same but it keeps saying "Automation Server can't create object". I did a reset to all the security settings of IE and they are equal to the settings that I have on Windows Server.

What else should I be looking for in order to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling **Initialize and script active-x control not marked as safe** setting from Internet option. If that also fails, keep protected mode off.

Comment: I tried that but still nothing. What doesn't make sense is that on Windows Server was simple as adding the url to the trusted sites list..and on this one should be the same.

Comment: There could be problem with your active-x control. Try loading any default IE active-x control like **Scripting.FileSystemObject**, if that succeeds then something needs to do with your active-x control. Additionally check if there is any x86 to x64 related issues.